# How to Display search results snippet on webpage

Tags: html, css, flask

I have to display some search results from database to my HTML page. I have a database and i am using Flask to send my search query and fetch results. Now when flask fetches the results, it displays the whole content on my web page which is around 100 lines. I only want to display 2-3 lines from the result . How can i do that ?

```
{% for result in results %}
        <a href={{ result['url'] }}>
            <h2>{{ result['name'] }}</h2>
        </a>
        <span class="badge badge-primary">{{ result['content'] }}</span>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

`

Comment: You need to show us your current code in order to help you

Comment: You can use pagination. Limit the number of records to be shown in single page. Get an idea of how pagination is done in https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ix-pagination

Comment: Here is the code for the page content being displayed : 
`{% for result in results %}
        <a href={{ result['url'] }}>
            <h2>{{ result['name'] }}</h2>
        </a>
        <span class="badge badge-primary">{{ result['content'] }}</span>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing SQL queries yourself can you limit keyword

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition limit 3
```

or you can pass to the template a list of 3 items

```
   return render_template("example.html", results= results[:3])
```